# How do I convert a RBG image to HSV and save the H, S, and V values into 3 separate images in C++ using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, rgb, hsv

I have an RBG picture that I want to convert into HSV. I want to save the H, S, and V values into 3 separate images. How would I do it?

My current code consists of just converting the RGB image to HSV:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat img_hsv, img_rgb;
img_rgb = imread("pic.png", 1);
cvtColor(img_rgb, img_hsv, COLORMAP_HSV);
```

Comment: Please check your post - there are lots of errors in it. Please also post complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `COLOR_BGR2HSV` instead of `COLORMAP_HSV`, as you're converting from BGR to HSV (OpenCV uses BGR by default). After that, you can split the image into its channels:

```
std::vector<Mat> channels;
split(img_hsv, channels);
```

And then save them one by one with a name of your choice:

```
imwrite("H.png", channels[0]);
imwrite("S.png", channels[1]);
imwrite("V.png", channels[2]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!